# UICollectionView flow layout issue

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I want to implement a collection view(scroll vertically) layout like the left of the following image. But when I use UICollectionViewFlowLayout, it looks like the right one. So is it possible to achieve this with flow layout, or I need to look into custom layout? Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom layout. The flow layout will arrange items in rows, then break onto the next row when it runs out of width, as you're seeing there.

There are plenty of "waterfall" style layouts available online, such as [this one](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout) which I've used a couple of times. You need to set a consistent column width and number of columns for these, though - I can't tell from your drawing if that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have managed to create my own custom layout which meet my scenario perfectly.

Comment: In my case, I can't use waterfall style since the width is not fixed. Actually, custom layout is easier that what I thought initially.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom `UICollectionViewLayout`, I have found this tutorial very useful:
[custom layout](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial)